# How to get total and percentage of values more than 10 in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql

I have written a SQL statement which yields Days taken and count of how many of each.

What I’d like to accomplish is a counts and percentages of how above and below 10 days there are.

Below sample data and what I'd like to achieve in colored texts.

[image]

Your help will be much appreciated thanks heaps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want the last two days, you can use:

```
select (case when days_take <= 10 then '10 or less' else 'greater than 10' end) as grp,
       count(*) * 100.0 / sum(count(*)) over () as percentage,
       count(*) as ratio
from t
group by (case when days_take <= 10 then '10 or less' else 'greater than 10' end);
```

Comment: Thank you so much @gordon-linoff - much appreciated

Comment: Now my issue is getting the percentages so it's rounded up to make it 100% as total of both <= and >= 10 days. I get this a result: 66.666666666666 and 33.333333333333, which is pretty much 99.99% ?

Comment: @Interalianz . . . In this case, the values should really be more like 66.6666667 and 33.3333333.  But the point is well taken.  The values might not add up to 100 due to rounding.  There is a fix, but it might mean that one of the values is rounded differently from the other values.

Comment: I am keen to see the workaround fix. Please share. Thanks heaps

Comment: Hi @Gordon Linoff, here's how I tweaked it to fit what I needed:   
Round(count(*) * 100 / sum(count(*)) over (),0) as Percentages
Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 0):

In TSQL, you can use `cross apply` and aggregation:

You can do conditional aggregation:

```
select 
    x.descr,
    1.0 * sum(x.how_many) / sum(sum(x.how_many)) over() as how_many_ratio,
    sum(x.how_many) as how_many_value
from mytable t
cross apply (values 
    (
        'greater than 10 days'
        case when days_taken > 10 then how_many else 0 end
    ),
    (
        'less than and 10 days'
        case when days_taken <= 10 then how_many else 0 end
    )
) as x(descr, how_many)
group by x.descr
```

If you are content with having all results on a single row, conditional aggregation is simpler:

```
select
    1.0 * sum(case when days_taken > 10 then how_many else 0 end)
        / sum(how_many) as how_many_above_10_ratio,
    sum(case when days_taken > 10 then how_many else 0 end) as how_many_above_10,
    1.0 * sum(case when days_taken <= 10 then how_many else 0 end)
        / sum(how_many) as how_many_below_10_ratio,
    sum(case when days_taken <= 10 then how_many else 0 end) as how_many_below_10
from mytable
```

Comment: Thanks for your input @GMB, much appreciated. I am still a newbie with SQL :-( Your comments I have file them away for future references. Thanks once again :-)